# Avoid code duplication with static classes in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm writing a **Java application** that will have to manage two different databases (let's say `Onebase` and `Twobase`) created using **PostgreSQL**.

In order to handle connections and queries, I created for the first one a file (named `OnebaseUtil`)  **with JDBC**, that more or less looks like this:

```
public class OnebaseUtil {
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/onebase?user=useradmin&password=123456";

    private static void dbConnect() { ... }

    private static void dbDisconnect() { ... }

    public static ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt) { ... }

    public static void dbExecuteUpdate(String sqlStmt) { ... }
}
```

Then I started writing the `TwobaseUtil`, just finding out **the code was exactly the same, except for the `url`** (`...twobase...` instead of `...onebase...`).

**How can I avoid having a code duplicate for both databases?**
Notice that as you can see all methods are `static` and I would like to keep using them as `static` through all the code.
I thought about using a single file (let's say `BothbaseUtil`) setting a constructor with the `String` passed every time I'm using it... but I would have to instantiate it every time! And I really want to avoid this.

Thanks anyone for help!

Comment: Do you want to work with any dependency injection framework, or are you okay with doing this on your own?

Comment: I would make them non-static. You wouldn't necessarily have to instantiate it every time: you could create the instances you want and keep references to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this database code pattern is seen very often, but has disadvantages.

One better would use a [DataSource](http://www.journaldev.com/2509/java-datasource-jdbc-datasource-example) and store several datasources declaratively in XML or properties. (Different for development/production).

One way to use such a DataSource would be using CDI, dependency injection. Then you would still have the freedom of creating unit tests by test data sources.

The open/close level and execute functions are tempting too, but try-with-resources and PreparedStatement are superior.

```
try (Connection con = ...) {
}
```

Closes the connection automatically even with return/exception.

```
try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepare...) {
    stm.setString(1, "me");
    try (ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The link you sent is being very helpful. Do you know what `DataSource` can I use for postgres 9.5.7?  I only found some for 7.3, but my IDE gives me warning as it's deprecated ones!
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/jdbc-datasource.html

Comment: I would need to search too. Personally I would create a **maven** project. Maven provides a build infrastructure sich library management, jars downloaded from remote to local repositories to the project. Then a maven search is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an `enum`.

```
enum Db {
    One("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/onebase?user=useradmin&password=123456"),
    Two("Something else");
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private final String url;


    Db(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    private static void dbConnect() { ... }

    private static void dbDisconnect() { ... }

    public static ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt) { ... }

    public static void dbExecuteUpdate(String sqlStmt) { ... }

}
```

Note that any methods that use the `url` filed will have to be removed from `static` but that shouldn't be a bad thing. You still only need them once in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the url to the method which connects to the database. That way you will first connect to the relevant DB and then perform the queries you need.